# Logging into a hidden user account remotely on Windows 7

Tags: windows, remote, user

There are a lot of tutorials/articles to create a user account in Windows. In fact, they are just hiding the particular user name from the logon screen. But I want to create an user account that should be hidden from Control panel too. The methods I've found so far, are about to make the account inactive.

`net user useraccount /active:yes|no`

This command hides the account from control panel by making it inactive. So the account can't be logged unless it's became active again.

Is there any way truly to hide an account from control panel, while make it loggable?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a huge security problem, to have hidden users. You might be able to work on hiding from low permission users, by hiding any directories and the control panel completely from them.

If you want to work in the background in concurrent sessions that is another issue. There are hacks that you can use, but every windows update will restore to the standard setup. Thus limiting permissions of the person you are hiding from is the likely best course, as they won't be able to install anything to correct your settings.

Comment: For some reasons, I've to give admin privileges. But in more than one admin available, I can't ensure all things going properly. (Like someone resets system admin password). Also hiding control panel widgets are not a best workaround. Because it just hides, not disable access. There is a couple of ways to get **useraccounts** rather than **control>users accounts**. So I'm interested in unofficial hacks too - @datatoo

Comment: what I meant was to make limited user permission available only. That typically won't even allow the person to do a windows update. If they have access only to their own directory, system files and everything else is hidden, there isn't much they can do. Even the cmd prompt won't let you do too much

Comment: Nope, I've to hive high privileges to people. So I can't go that way. Thanks for your time.